# Should a Windows Service be re-installed when upgrading .NET framework?

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-services, installutil

If we upgrade (a re-deploy) a windows service to a newer .NET framework using new features, should the service be uninstalled from its server and re-installed using the latest 'InstallUtils.exe' from the newest framework? Or is the install in the registries independant from the .NET framework?

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know my stuff, but if the newer version is, like, ***very*** newer, you should reinstall the whole thing. I wouldn't take the gamble.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.